# Scroll the document so that the clicked element appears on top of a page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So here is a bottleneck:

When clicking on a tile it expands (with text), I need to place the page so that clicked tile (hence activated) is at the top of a page. And the same for other tiles
Basically I need to reposition clicked element to be on top:

Here is a part of JS for the single element:

```
expandItem(idx) {
    // Need to make this logic here
    // scroll to the beginning of the section if tablet screen
    const tabletWidth = window.innerWidth > 767 && window.innerWidth < 1170;
    if (tabletWidth) {
      scrollTo(this.gridContainer);
    }
    this.setState({
      activeItem: idx
    })
  }

const GridItem = ({ content, currentState, expandItem, collapseItem }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`fancy_grid_single_item ${currentState}`} onClick={expandItem}>
      <div className="small_tile_content">
        <LazyImg src={content.icon} alt={content.name} />
        <h3>
          {content.name}
        </h3>
        <span className='grid_item_view_more_btn'>
          <LazyImg src={AngleDoubleDown} alt="view more" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="active_tile_content">
        <h3>{content.name}</h3>
        <p>{content.description}</p>
        <button className='grid_item_close' onClick={collapseItem}>
          <LazyImg src={AngleDoubleDown} alt="close" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div >
  )
}
```

Image here
[Clicking on ISV & Technology make it at the top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j8kt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the image with an anchor tag and using href to get the element into view?

For example, if your image currently is defined like -

```
<img src="someIcon.png" id="someImg"/>
```

Make it like -

```
<a href="#someImg"><img src="someIcon.png" id="someImg"/></a>
```

We've wrapped the image tag with an anchor tag. The click on the image will be received by the anchor tag and this will get the element defined with id="someImg" into view and to the top of the page (provided there's enough content below it)

In your case, wrapping the element -

```
<LazyImg src={content.icon} alt={content.name} />
```

with an anchor tag should be enough along with providing an id

---

Edit : here's a pure JS option of doing it (without changing URL) -

1. You get the Y co-ordinate of the html element by -

```
var yCoord = document.querySelector('#someImg').getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

2. Use window.scrollTo with the yCoord

```
window.scrollTo(0,yCoord);
```

Comment: I am not sure if I want to change the url with hashes being added. Although I 've tried your suggestion and it did not work, hence I am disabling links default behavior via css. Thank you ^^

Comment: Edited the answer with a way to achieve this without changing URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollIntoView`,onClick pass the div `id` as parameter to the `goToStep` function.

```
  goToStep = (stepId) =>{
    this.setState({
      atTop:stepId
    },()=>{
            var content = document.getElementById('transitToTop'+(stepId));
            content.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
          }
    );
  }
```

trigger event

```
<button className="btn btnStep" onClick={()=>this.goToStep(divid)}>scroll to div</button>
```